# Rails routing example

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I am trying to port a working rails 2.4 app to rails 4.2. I cannot get the routing to work.

the URL of x.pdf is broken into id.format and passed as params to a report controller.

in Rails 2.4 I have

```
map.report ':id.:format', :controller => :reports, :action => :generate
```

in Rails 4.2 I am trying to use

```
get ':id.:format' => 'reports#generate'
```

but when i run the app and browse to http://www.example.com/x.pdf, i get the fatal error

> ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/x"):

When I run rake routes I get:

```
Prefix Verb     URI Pattern               Controller#Action
    GET      /:id.:format              reports#generate
```

I am using Ruby 2.3.0, Rails 4.2.5, NGINX 1.9.9, Passenger 5.0.23

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change `get ':id.:format'` to just `get ':id'`

Comment: will that allow me to still get pdf as a format param based on the .xxx then? In the old app I could specify different formats like .xml to render the report in.

Comment: Yeah you'll just add .pdf to the end of the URL and if the controller is set up correctly, Rails should take care of the mapping.

Comment: Looks correct, when i rake routes now I get GET      /:id(.:format)            reports#generate